# TinyMCE: get values from a listbox in a modal window

Tags: javascript, wordpress, listbox, tinymce

I'm creating a TinyMCE Plugin for Wordpress. It has a `textbox` and a `listbox` field, both staying in a modal window.
Code below:

```
(function () {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.windowdata', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('showModal', {
                title: 'Show Modal',
                image: url + '/img/button.png',
                onclick: function () {
                    ed.windowManager.open({
                        title: 'Minestra',
                        body: [
                            {type: 'textbox', name: 'Field', label: 'Number', value: '', tooltip: 'Tooltip', maxLength: 3, classes: 'i1n'}, //textbox
                            {type: 'listbox', label: 'Listbox', classes: 'i1lb', values: [
                                {text: '', value: ''},
                                {text: 'Number', value: 'lone_number'},
                                {text: 'Bar', value: 'bar'},
                            ]}, //listbox
                        ],
                        onsubmit: function () {
                            var n1 = document.getElementsByClassName('mce-i1n')[0].value; //textbox value
                            var t1 = document.getElementsByClassName('mce-i1lb')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].getElementsByClassName('mce-txt')[0].innerHTML; //listbox value

                            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, n1+' is of type '+t1) //write contents
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
    }
)
```

My question is about how to get the field values. What i did works very well with the `textbox` (the `n1` var inside the `onsubmit()` method), but the `listbox` gets the same text that is shown to TinyMCE user (the text var in each listbox item).

What i want is a way to get the value instead; plus, i suppose i didn't get the right way to do it, not even with textbox. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to generate content is:

```
onsubmit: function (e) {
    // Insert content when the window form is submitted
              e.insertContent('Textbox content: ' + e.data.Field);
              e.insertContent('Listbox content: ' + e.data.Listbox)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by my own: i had to give a name to all of my fields:

```
    {type: 'textbox', name: 'Field', label: 'Number', value: '', tooltip: 'Tooltip', maxLength: 3, classes: 'i1n'}, //textbox
    {type: 'listbox', name: 'Listbox', label: 'Listbox', classes: 'i1lb', values: [
        {text: '', value: ''},
        {text: 'Number', value: 'lone_number'},
        {text: 'Bar', value: 'bar'},
    ]
```

At this point, to generate my content i got values this way:

```
onsubmit: function (e) {
    e.data.Field;
    e.data.Listbox;
}
```

and used this to write in TinyMCE textarea. To get values back i had to modify textbox field this way:

```
{type: 'textbox', name: 'Field', label: 'Number', value: '', tooltip: 'Tooltip', maxLength: 3, classes: 'i1n', value: ed.selection.getContent()}
```

Similarly with listbox